# Ayuda deployment en shinyapps.io

Tags: r, deployment, shiny

Estoy tratando de hacer el deploy de una app en shiny y obtengo la siguiente pantalla de error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ya no tengo llamadas a documentos (tipo csv o imágenes) en otras carpetas, ni tampoco declaro nuevos paths o cambios de directorio. Así se encuentra la carpeta de dónde trato de hacer el deploy. Ayuda! Este es el estado de la carpeta:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

yo intentaría -para descartar- cambiar el nombre del xml y remover la tilde (y por tanto también modificar la ruta en el `app.R`, o en su defecto cambiar el encoding de tus scripts a `UTF-8` en caso que no lo hagas.

Intenta y cuéntanos como te fue.